# MySql: How can update date from timestamp to datetime

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

I have 2 table, Table `users` i save date in `timestamp`, But table `an_users`.

Now i need to update new table called `an_users` and get the date like `datetime`.

I try this query:-

```
UPDATE an_users JOIN users 
    ON an_users.ID = users.uid
SET an_users.user_registered = users.created , 
an_users.user_email = users.mail
```

But the error is user_registered save date like `0000-00-00 00:00:00`, It must be like `2014:01:05 10:00:20`.

Where is error

Answer (score 0):

use `from_unixtime`

```
UPDATE an_users JOIN users 
    ON an_users.ID = users.uid
SET an_users.user_registered = from_unixtime(users.created),
an_users.user_email = users.mail
```

Comment: Hi ... its show me date  like this 1970-01-01 02:00:00 ??

Comment: @Rasha Sami, can try now